# Use of Mockito given/willThrow in JUnit @Nested classes

Tags: spring-mvc, mockito, junit5

I'm using Junit 5 and Mockito to test Spring controllers. My controller uses a service, annotated with @Mockbean in my test class. To organize my tests, I user @Nested classes. I use Mockito given/willThrow to mock the fact that my service can throw exceptions. Then if the service throws a particular exception type, the controller returns a corresponding status code.
So in a @Nested class, I have for example :

```
@Test
@SneakyThrows
void test_404() {
    String message = "message";
        
    given(myService.doSomething(anyLong())).willThrow(new CustomExceptionOne(message));

    mockMvc.perform(get("/api/doSomething")
       .contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
       .andExpect(status().isNotFound())
       .andExpect(content().string(message))
       .andReturn();
}
```

And in the same class, I have a whole test suite where I test that when the service throws CustomExceptionTwo, the controller returns status 409, CustomExceptionThree returns 412 and so on. And if I have an unpredicted Exception, the controller returns 500.

All the tests works if I run them one by one. If I run the whole suite (eiter just the @Nested class or the upper class), it seems that it's the first Mockito given that decides what other given will return. For example if the 404 test is the first to run, all the other test will fail because all the other Mockito given will return CustomExceptionOne instead of what is written in the test.

If I put all my test methods in the upper class instead of the @Nested class, all the tests pass.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Spring / Spring boot version?

Answer (score 0):

To my eyes, you ran into one of:

- [@MockBean fields are not reset for JUnit 5 @Nested tests #12470](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12470)
- [@MockBean fields are not reset for JUnit 5 @Nested tests using @WebMvcTest #23984](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/23984)

Both issues are marked as solved in 2.4.x, consider upgrading to that version.

Comment: Thank you, it works ! I searched a lot but I thought it was a Mockito issue.